# tryhaskell.org does not seem to support GHCi commands

Tags: haskell, ghci

When I use GHCi commands (i.e. any command starting with `":"` for example `:set +t`) on https://tryhaskell.org/ I get an error:

> :1:1: parse error on input ‘:’

According to the documentation of GHCi this should work, but I cannot find much information about it.

I've tried a few other online "repls" as well.

Comment: Well, not even `x = 1` works :/

Comment: tryhaskell.org doesn't use GHCi, it uses an interpreter based on [`hint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint).

Comment: I'm pretty impressed that there's an accepted answer to this. At the end of your writing, I don't even know what your question is. In future posts, you might want to be a bit more explicit about what you're hoping to see in a good answer.

Comment: @DanielWagner, yes, understood, but this is quite a stumbling block as a beginner, and will serve some purpose in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That repl probably doesn't try to provide all of GHCI's functionality. It probably wants to be stateless, so it just evaluates expressions one at a time. No variable definitions, no interacting with GHCI any other way, e.g. through `:t`. If you install GHCI yourself, you will have a functioning repl. Or, if you want an online repl, https://replit.com/languages/haskell seems to work fine for me.